# I'm trying to create an ArrayList of arrays but it won't compile properly

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Here is my code.  The line where I try to add shows up as  expected, for both italian and add. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class RestaurantSelector1 {

    static final String[] italian = {"Pepolino Restaurant", "Locanda Verde", "Scalini Fedeli", "Gran Morsi", "Ecco", "Tutto il Giorno", "The Odeon", "Mamo Restaurant", "Petrarca Cucina E Vino", "Osteria Morini"};
    static final String[] japanese = {"Shigure", "Sushi Azabu", "Ichimura", "Brushstroke", "Takahachi Tribeca Restaurant", "Ninja New York", "DOMODOMO", "Sushi of Gari", "Hirohisa", "Blue Ribbon"};
    static final String[] french = {"Bouley", "Batard", "Racines", "The Odeon", "MAMO Restaurant", "La Sirene", "Le Coucou", "Balthazar", "Taureau", "L'Appart"};
    static final String[] american = {"American Cut Steakhouse", "Marc Forgione", "The Bennett", "Little Park", "The Odeon", "Yves", "Tribeca Grill", "Atera", "Batard", "Brandy Library"};
    static final String[] chinese = {"Mr. Chow", "Macao", "Khe-Yo"};
    static final String[] spanish = {"Tablao", "Sazon", "Despana", "Estancia 460", "Westside Coffee Shop", "Anejo Tribeca", "Terra Wine Bar", "Darlene", "Sophia's Cuban Cuisine", "Amada"};
    static final String[] cafe = { "Arcade Bakery", "Galerie de Cafe", "The Wooly Daily", "Cafe Belle", "Baked", "Laughing Man Coffee and Tea","La Colombe Coffee", "Kuro-Obi at Canal Street Market", "Blue Spoon Coffee", "Everyman Espresso"};
    static final String[] thai = {"khe-yo", "Empire", "Macao"};
    static final String[] indian = {"Tamarind"};
    static final String[] viatnamese = {"Khe-Yo", "Macao"};

    ArrayList<String[]> cuisine = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    cuisine.add(italian);

}
```

Comment: `cuisine.add(italian);` should be either inside constructor, method, or initialization block. It can't be placed at class level (now where is that duplicate).

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: ah! RIGHT! Thank you!!